# Nested rounded border graphic over text within <span></span> tags?

Tags: html, css, styling

Is it possible to get the effect of having nested rounded rectangles signifying each `<span></span>` grouping?

For example, in html sourcecode

```
<span>She <span>loves</span> him a <span>lot</span>.</span>
```

Would look like this:

[image]

Ideally it could handle something like 20 nested levels graphically.
It's important it work with span tags as opposed to using divs or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that

```css
span{
    display:inline-block;
}

span:first-child{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:10px;
}
span:last-child{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<span>She <span>loves</span> him a <span>lot</span>.</span>
```